# is There an easy way to get all data from vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have this data's is there a way to get all of these? 
already tried `this._data.forEach` but it is not working thanks!

```
data() {
  return {
    childData: '',
    credit: '',
    company: '',
    email: '',
    first_name: '',
    middle_name: '',
    terms: '',
    last_name: '',
    phone: '',
    mobile: '',
    fax: '',
    street: '',
    city: '',
    country: '',
    state: '',
    zip_code: '',
    as_of: '',
    account_number: '',
    website:'',
    open_balance: '',
    notes: '',
    files: null,
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue uses underscore as a prefix for its internal properties. You should avoid using them.

The data object for an instance is accessible via the `$data` property.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data

So within an instance you can get that object using `this.$data`.

In the question you mentioned trying to use `forEach`. Not sure what you're trying to do but objects don't have a native `forEach` method. The usual looping mechanisms for an object are available on `$data`, such as `for`/`in` or grabbing the array of keys:

```js
Object.keys(this.$data)
```

Comment: what i want is get all of data and pass it as a payload for the axios,
is there a way make it easier?

cause if I do it manually I would need to pass it as {dataname: this.data}

Answer (score 0):

wrap it again

```
data() {
  return {
    data: {
        childData: '',
        credit: '',
        company: '',
        email: '',
        first_name: '',
        middle_name: '',
        terms: '',
        last_name: '',
        phone: '',
        mobile: '',
        fax: '',
        street: '',
        city: '',
        country: '',
        state: '',
        zip_code: '',
        as_of: '',
        account_number: '',
        website:'',
        open_balance: '',
        notes: '',
        files: null,
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I didnt think of that LOL, thanks will try this one

Comment: Good luck my friend ;-)

Comment: that the data is an object and the foreach does not support it

Comment: Like skirtle said: foreeach is not for objects. Iterate with [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) instead.